# Spring GridFsOperations API for storing in mongo with a custom prefix

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, gridfs

I am using GridFsOperations API of spring-data for mongodb to store large files in chunks in the db. Here is my code:

```
@Autowired
private GridFsOperations gridOperation;

public String save(InputStream inputStream, String contentType, String filename) {
  ...
  GridFSFile file = gridOperation.store(inputStream, filename, metaData);
  return file.getId().toString();
}
```

The code works fine but it always stores files in collections starting with prefix "fs", which is the default in mongodb. Is there a way to specify a different prefix so that I can have different files and chunks for different kinds of files to be stored?

EDIT: additional question

How do I specify the chunk size? Is it advisable to have different chunk sizes for different kinds of files, for example - 2 mb for image files and 10 mb for video files?

Comment: alright, I found out how to use other prefixes using GridFSTemplate directly instead of GridFSOperations, which seems to be still under development. Now, all I want to know is how to fix the chunk size and whether its good to force a particular size in mongo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solutions to both my questions (configure chunk sizes in my code and use different prefixes) using GridFS and GridFSInputFile classes instead of GridFSTemplate or GridFSOperations.

I still want to know if its advisable to have different chunk sizes.

For anybody who may want to know, here is the code snippet:

```
@Autowired
private MongoDbFactory dbFactory;

public String save(InputStream inputStream, String contentType, String filename, String username, String bucket) {
  DBObject metaData = ....(create metadata here)

  GridFS gridFS = new GridFS(dbFactory.getDb(), bucket);
    GridFSInputFile gridFSInputFile = gridFS.createFile(inputStream);
    gridFSInputFile.setMetaData(metaData);

    if(bucket.equals("photo")){
        gridFSInputFile.setChunkSize(1024000);  //1 mb
    } else if(bucket.equals("mp3")){
        gridFSInputFile.setChunkSize(10240000); //10 mb
    }

    try {
        gridFSInputFile.saveChunks();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gridFSInputFile.save();

    return gridFSInputFile.getId().toString();
}
```

Comment: You are directly using MongoDB Java APIs. Would be good if Spring-Data enhances it's GridFS APIs to support selecting the buckets while storing the documents.